# max_cut in qiskit aqua

Tags: qiskit

Happened on some code, which I was hoping would run out of the box. However fails on the import

```
from qiskit.aqua.translators.ising import max_cut
```

I've not been able to find the module in the documentation. Any ideas how to solve this? Other then use an earlier version of Qiskit?

I get the following error:

```
from qiskit.aqua.translators.ising import max_cut
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.aqua.translators'
```

Comment: What error do you receive? When I try running that import it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: I realized I did not have my Qiskit up to the newest version. I'm receiving the same error now. The max_cut class was moved to the following import path: `from qiskit.optimization.ising import max_cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that docplex class also was moved to from qiskit.optimization.ising import docplex

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use comments for posts like this.